# Laravel Array or Object?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, collections

i'm kinda new with Laravel Framework. And now confused with data type like array and object. I got a data like this :

```
"data[0].detailItem" => array:2 [
   0 => array:3 [
        "itemNo" => "100011"
        "unitPrice" => 0
        "quantity" => 6
   ]
   1 => array:3 [
        "itemNo" => "102972"
        "unitPrice" => 0
        "quantity" => 3
   ]
```

]

is there a way I change it into :

```
"data[0].detailItem" => [
  {
    "itemNo" => "100011"
    "unitPrice" => 0
    "quantity" => 6
  },
  {
    "itemNo" => "102972"
    "unitPrice" => 0
    "quantity" => 3
  }
]
```

Edit :
Heres the code

```
public function apiStore(Request $request){
    $detailReceiveItem = DB::table('t_receive_item_detail')->where('receive_item_id','=',$request->idReceiveItem)->get();
    $detailItem = [];
    foreach($detailReceiveItem as $key=>$receiveItem){
        $temp = [
            'itemNo' => $receiveItem->item_code,
            'unitPrice' => 0,
            'quantity' => $receiveItem->qty,
        ];
        array_push($detailItem,$temp);
    }
    $input = [
        'data[0].vendorNo' => $request->vendorNo,
        'data[0].receiveNumber' => $request->receiveNumber,
        'data[0].transDate' => date('d/m/Y',strtotime($request->transDate)),
        'data[0].detailItem' => (object)$detailItem
    ];
    
    $insertReceiveItem = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.session()->get('access_token'),
        'X-Session-ID' => session()->get('X-Session-ID'),
    ])->asForm()->post(session()->get('host').'api url here',$input);
    
    return response()->json(['status'=>1, 'url'=>'/api-accurate/receive-item','message'=>'Receive Item Created Successfully!']);
}
```

That's my code. I need to convert $detailItem into a object.

Comment: why would you need to cast it to object? btw you can cast any array to object using `(object)["a" => 1]`

Comment: i need to send the data as a HTTP Client request and it need to be as an object. I've tried (object) but it return as collection,is still same value?

Comment: can you share the code related to that request

Comment: I think you're looking for [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @ChinhNguyen I've edited my post with my code

Comment: @Nick unfortunately HTTP Client Request not accepting JSON value, i've tried that method and sending me error : Expected Array, string given

Comment: Well, to follow Chinh's suggestion, change `'data[0].detailItem' => (object)$detailItem` to `'data[0].detailItem' => $detailItem` and `array_push($detailItem,$temp);` to `array_push($detailItem,(object)$temp);`

Comment: @Nick thank you for answering, i tried your way and it changed a bit. `0 =>{#1963+"itemNo": "100011"+"unitPrice": 0+"quantity": 6}` how I remove `0=>{#1963` ?

Comment: It would probably help if you could give some information on exactly what the API expects (do you have a link to documentation perhaps?).

Comment: @Nick that's why I got stuck, it's because the API doesn't provide a clear instruction about the data they're expecting. I've contacted with their team but so slow respon. that's why I try my luck here. lol

Comment: Unfortunately without that we're just guessing... :(

Comment: yes tha't what i'm talking about, and it so frustrating. but, Thanks for answering @Nick